# Is there a way to Union Two tables in Impala SQL when No. of Columns are not equal without defining each Column as NuLL

Tags: sql, impala

I have a Sample table where I have around 100 columns. In the Other table I have 20 columns. These 20 columns are common in both the tables. I want to take Union of both the tables. The way I doing it is I have to do select var1 as null, select var2 as null and so on for all 80 columns which are not common in the tables. Is there a better way to do this. Like all the columns which are not common automatically take NUll value?
Thanks

Comment: No. input to `Union` must be the same number of columns with matching (or implicitly castable) data types.

Comment: Thanks @ Stu .So that means for 80 columns which are not present in Table1, I have to define each variable as NULL in Table 2 to combine the Output? Is not that really a shortcoming in SQL?

Comment: If you want the 80 columns that only exist in one table to be in the result set, they must exist in both `select` queries. Is it a shortcoming? No - the columns are combined by ordinal position only, not by name or any other attribute, it's not the query optimizer's job to guess what you want. - SQL is a declarative language. I've never needed this in 25 years of using databases, it's probably a fundamental design flaw in your domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can fool the compiler into generating the columns using a `left join` and `using`:

```
select *
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where 1=0  -- an empty table but it has the additional columns
     ) t2
     using (col1, col2, . . . , col20)
union all
select *
from t2;
```

Note:  This assumes that the first 20 columns that are used for matching are in the same order in the two tables.